# Use Ransack to search in Clob field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, clob, ransack

I'm using ransack with oracle for a search form. One of the fields i'm searching in is a CLOB (comment_text). My search param is:

```
q[message_comments_comment_text_cont] = 'lorem ipsum'
```

The resulting query is:

```
SELECT "MESSAGES".* FROM "MESSAGES" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "MESSAGE_COMMENTS"
ON "MESSAGE_COMMENTS"."MESSAGE_ID" = "MESSAGES"."ID"
WHERE "MESSAGE_COMMENTS"."COMMENT_TEXT" LIKE empty_clob()
```

Can anyone tell me how to prevent, whatever is causing this, replacing my search string with empty_clob?